# How to close an alert without going back to index.html?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created a small website using [this](https://html5up.net/uploads/demos/dimension/#) template. I also added an alert message on the top that appears automatically when the website is opened:

```
.alert {
    padding:5px;
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
    position:fixed; 
    top:0px; 
    left:0px; 
    width:100%; 
}

.close {
    color:white;
    float:right;
    font-size:20px;
    line-height:10px;
    cursor:pointer;
}


    <div class="alert">
        <span class="close" onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none';">&times;</span>
        <p style="text-align: center;">Message</p>
    </div>
```

The problem is that if you open a page, let's say "Contact", and then decide to close the alert message, you'd go back to index.html. How can I prevent this and allow the user to stay on the same page after the alert message has been closed?

Comment: this is not a css problem, it looks more like a javascript or php problem. could you add the code you are using to generate the alert message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main.js file contains a piece of code that will hide the article when you click outside the article (#main).

```
$body.on('click', function(event) {

                // Article visible? Hide.
                    if ($body.hasClass('is-article-visible'))
                        $main._hide(true);

            });
```

So to prevent your alert from going back to the main page by canceling the click function of the #main on clicking the cancel button.

```
                    $(".close,.alert").on('click', function(event) {
                        event.stopPropagation();
                    });
```

This code should work as far as I can tell. Please include a https://jsfiddle.net/ or a http://codepen.io/pen/ with your code. So we can test or solution before giving you an answer without downloading the template and adding your code.